# How another user can connect to my Hyperledger network in Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I created sample blockchain network. How to allow another user connect to it and make transactions?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the [online playground](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/login) then your network is stored under a "Web Browser" connection and your Business Network is run and stored only within your browser's local storage.  However you could Export your network (definition only not data) and share the BNA file with another user who can then import it - but you have separate copies.

If you want to completely share with another user you will need to share an underlying Hyperledger Fabric - then both download and install Playground locally and share Business Network Cards to connect to the same Fabric.

Comment: Therefore I should download file bna and send it to another person.  This person should import the same network to online playground and get copy of my network. But it will be just separate instance of my network, no more. Correct?

Comment: Thanks. I've installe Hyperledger Composer in local environment and can run example of network (created step by step from here https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/installing/development-tools.html